# Real time NI-DAQ data plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, real-time-data, nidaqmx

I'm trying to get a real time plot of data I'm acquiring with a NI USB-6008. I tried doing the same with arduino and got a plot exactly as I wanted (see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/08kzU.jpg), and the x-axis would move in real-time, but I couldn't define the sampling rate. With NI I was able to define the sampling rate I wanted but I can't display the data in a continuous, real-time plot, I can only see 1 sec at a time and I need to be able to have access to all the data acquired since I want to measure a real-time EEG. I'm a new matlab user, so please consider no previous knowledge.

This is the code I've got so far:

```
clear
close all

dq = daq("ni");
ch1 = addinput(dq, "Dev1", "ai0", "Voltage");
dq.Rate = 1000;
dq.ScansAvailableFcn = @(src,evt) plotDataAvailable(src, evt);
dq.ScansAvailableFcnCount = 100;
start(dq, "Duration", seconds(5))

while dq.Running
    pause(0.5);
end

time = 0;
data = 0;
n = ceil(dq.Rate/10);

%Set up Plot
figure(1)
plotGraph = plot(time,data); 
title('DAQ data log','FontSize',15);
xlabel ('Elapsed Time (s)','FontSize',10); ylabel('Voltage (V)','FontSize',10);
h = animatedline;
ax = gca;
ax.YGrid = 'on';
ax.XGrid = 'on';
h = animatedline;
function plotDataAvailable(src, ~)
    while ishandle(plotGraph) % Loop when Plot is Active will run until plot is closed
        data = read(dq,n);
        t =  datetime('now');
        % Add points to animation
        addpoints(h,datenum(t),data)
        % Update axes
        ax.XLim = datenum([t-seconds(15) t]);
        datetick('x','keeplimits')
        drawnow
    end
end
```

This was my previous arduino code that showed me the plot I needed (with the wrong sampling rate):

```
clear
clc

%User Defined Properties 
a = arduino('com4','uno');              % Define the Arduino Communication port
plotTitle = 'Arduino Data Log';         % Plot title

%Define Function Variables
time = 0;
data = 0;

%Set up Plot
figure(1)
plotGraph = plot(time,data,'-r' ); 
title(plotTitle,'FontSize',15);
xlabel ('Elapsed Time (s)','FontSize',10); ylabel('Voltage (V)','FontSize',10);
h = animatedline;
ax = gca;
ax.YGrid = 'on';
ax.XGrid = 'on';
ax.YLim = [0 5];            % Sets y-min and y-max
while ishandle(plotGraph) % Loop when Plot is Active will run until plot is closed
        startIteration = tic;
        voltagem = readVoltage(a,'A0')
        t =  datetime('now');
        % Add points to animation
        addpoints(h,datenum(t),voltagem)
        % Update axes
        ax.XLim = datenum([t-seconds(15) t]);
        datetick('x','keeplimits')
        drawnow
end
```

I've tried using this while loop on my NI data but it doesn't work.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're sampling at 1000Hz, and your callback function is called whenever there are 1000 samples in the buffer, so it is only natural that it will be called at intervals of (about) 1 second. In general, if you want to call the callback function with a frequency of fCallback, you need to set the number of samples available to `fSampling/fCallback`. So, for example, if you want to plot at a frequency of 10Hz (every 0.1s), the number of samples must be set to `1000/10 = 100`.

Comment: Furthermore, you're creating new `animatedline`s at every call of your callback function, which is exactly what `animatedline`s are supposed to help you prevent doing. Create the `animatedline`s before you start sampling, and then just `addpoints` to them whenever new data is available.

Comment: But I need the plot to show me at least 10 seconds of data and I need to be able to have access to all the data I record and not only the last 10 seconds.
Regarding the `addpoints` function, it won't work because the data I get from the NI is not a double

Comment: 1) the total sampling duration (your 10s) has *nothing* to do with the `ScansAvailableFcnCount` property. As I said above, this only tells the program how often to call the callback function, so that's what you need to change.  2) `read()` returns double, so there is no problem.  3) even if it didn't, you can always cast variables to other types.

Comment: Oh! Ok I've fixed that.
Now I can't figure out why my code isn't working at all. I don't know if I can do the same as I did with arduino, but this is what I have so far. Can you take a look please? Thank you so much for your help btw

Comment: Just [edit] your initial question, there is no formatting in the comments.

Comment: Ok! There you go, I've updated my code. But it doesn't work

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Does your NI USB-6008 catch fire? Matlab plots the Mona Lisa instead of your data?

Comment: It just won't run... It won't plot anything. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywlvf.png here you have the error but it's more than 1000 lines...

Answer (score 0):

You've got the order of the operations wrong. What your code is doing at the moment is:

1. initialize the data acquisition
2. read the data from the hardware while trying to add data to lines that don't exist
3. initialize the animated lines.

Furthermore, in your `addpoints` call you're trying to plot t, which is a scalar, and data, which is an array.

What you should do instead is:

```
clear
close all

% Set up the plot
figure(1)
title('DAQ data log','FontSize',15);
xlabel ('Elapsed Time (s)','FontSize',10)
ylabel('Voltage (V)','FontSize',10);
h = animatedline;
ax = gca;
ax.YGrid = 'on';
ax.XGrid = 'on';

% Set up the data acquisition
dq = daq("ni");
ch1 = addinput(dq, "Dev1", "ai0", "Voltage");
dq.Rate = 1000;
dq.ScansAvailableFcn = {@plotDataAvailable, h, ax}; % pass also the handle to the line and to the axes
dq.ScansAvailableFcnCount = 100;

% Now you start the data acquisition
start(dq, "Duration", seconds(5))


function plotDataAvailable(src, evt, h, ax)
    data = read(dq, n);
    % maybe your time array should look something like this?
    t = datetime(now) - seconds((length(data)-1:-1:0)./src.Rate);

    % Add points to animated line
    addpoints(h, datenum(t), data)

    % Update axes
    % ax.XLim = datenum([t-seconds(15) t]); % this line is useless, why would you have a 15s window when your data acquisition is only 5s long?
    datetick('x','keeplimits')
    drawnow

end
```

I can't try this at the moment, so it might not work exactly.

Comment: I think this line doesn't work `dq.ScansAvailableFcn = {@plotDataAvailable, h, ax}; % pass also the handle to the line and to the axes` and I've tried other things like `dq.ScansAvailableFcn = @plotDataAvailable(src,evt,h,ax);` or `dq.ScansAvailableFcn = @(src,evt,h,ax) plotDataAvailable(src,evt,h,ax);` or `dq.ScansAvailableFcn = @(h,ax) plotDataAvailable(h,ax);` or `dq.ScansAvailableFcn = @(src, evt) plotDataAvailable(h,ax);` or `dq.ScansAvailableFcn = @(src, evt) plotDataAvailable(src,evt,h,ax);`
But nothing seems to work and I don't really know how this line of code works

Comment: That line is 100% correct. Also, "it doesn't work" is not a valid comment, explain *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: It says "Specify ScansAvailableFcn as a scalar function handle." and when I put it like this `dq.ScansAvailableFcn = @(src,evt,h,ax) plotDataAvailable(src,evt,h,ax);` it doesn't work either, and it gives like a 1000 lines of error.

Comment: I think that that line is not the only problem. Can you try it whenever you have time please?

Comment: Also, data = read(dq,n) is returning a matrix, I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

So I think I finally got it, because I got the plot like I wanted, with the x-axis moving with real-time. However I still get an error saying "Unrecognized table variable name 'Dev1_ai0'" event tho I checked that's the name of the row that I want. Anyways, this is what my code looks now.

```
clear
close all

time = 0;
data = 0;

% Set up the plot
figure(1)
plotGraph = plot(time,data,'-r' ); 
title('DAQ data log','FontSize',15);
xlabel ('Elapsed Time (s)','FontSize',10)
ylabel('Voltage (V)','FontSize',10);
h = animatedline;
ax = gca;
ax.YGrid = 'on';
ax.XGrid = 'on';

% Set up the data acquisition
dq = daq("ni");
ch1 = addinput(dq, "Dev1", "ai0", "Voltage");
dq.Rate = 1000;

% Start the data acquisition
start(dq, "Duration", seconds(10))
n = ceil(dq.Rate/10);


while ishandle(plotGraph)
    data = read(dq, n);
    voltage = data.Dev1_ai0;
    
    t = datetime('now');
    
    for i = 1:100
    % Add points to animated line
        if isvalid(h)
        addpoints(h, datenum(t), voltage(i))
        end
    end

    % Update axes
    ax.XLim = datenum([t-seconds(15) t]);
    datetick('x','keeplimits')
    drawnow

end

disp('Plot Closed')
```